# pandas dataframe: finding average of weight for average age samples, group them by gender

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, average

So far I can get the average age of the data:

```
np.mean(df.age)
```

As well as the average weight sorted by gender:

```
df.groupby(by='gender')['weight'].mean()
```

But I don't know how to put the condition of how I need to find the average weight of people who are above the average age only, and show it by gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter and groupby:

```
mean_age = df['age'].mean()

out = df[df['age']>mean_age].groupby('gender')['weight'].mean()
```

On the other note, you may want to filter by average age per gender:

```
mean_age = df.groupby('gender')['age'].transform('mean')

out = df[df['age']>mean_age].groupby('gender')['weight'].mean()
```

Once you have that, you can plot with

```
out.plot.bar()
```